# What methodology to build an electronic system?

Tags: circuit-design

Electronic engineering is not my field but I enjoy build some very little electronic circuits for fun. When I try to build something, I have no methodology at all: I try, fail and try again until my circuit does what I want.

I think it is not an efficient way to produce things (even if it is interesting to learn new stuff). That's why I'm wondering if there are methods that can be used to build an entire electronic systems just from a set of requirements. What are the steps? How to choose the best components?

Comment: Good decisions come from experience. Experience usually comes as a consequence of bad decisions. Keep doing what you're doing, but take notes, and try to learn from your mistakes. Any engineer that appears to know what they're doing that I've talked to, and it's true for me too, has done a lot of doing, a lot, usually after having some education in the field as well. Education is basically trying to learn from other peoples' mistakes instead of your own.

Comment: You might as well be asking the same question about steam engines.

Comment: Get a copy of Art of Electronics and read it

Comment: @DirkBruere Do you think that maybe [Learning the Art of Electronics A Hands-On Lab Course](https://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/physics/electronics-physicists/learning-art-electronics-hands-lab-course) could be better for the OP, seeing as they apparently like the hands-on approach to learning? (I don't have that book myself.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton The idea is to mix the approaches. The AoE can be used as a guide and a reference but it is also something that needs to be consulted before soldering if one is a beginner. Save s some smoke and money. BTW. for those who do not know AoE is popular because of its simplicity as well as its comprehensive coverage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That's why I'm wondering if there are methods that can be used to build an entire electronic systems just **from a set of requirements**.

- You've got the fundamentals right. Start with a list of requirements and specifications.
- Next, break the system down into functional blocks. For example, an audio mixer would include

  - Power supply.
  - Input module

    - Preamplifier / gain control
    - Tone control
    - Pan (panorama) control
  - Output module
  - Headphone amplifier
  - VU (volume unit) indicators

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxnOSe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Audio mixer block diagram.*

Each of these blocks would have their own sub-specification and can be designed and built from reference designs with tweaks to meet the requirements of your project. It should be clear that each block can be designed in sequence and tested before moving on to the next section.

A final part of the exercise might be to see if certain sections can be merged to reduce the component count, power consumption, PCB area, etc. In this example an obvious one would be to combine the preamp and tone controls.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to find existing schematics and descriptions of what you want to do, on the internet. You may find somebody else who tried to do the same thing. But be aware that he can be an amateur like you. And that informations can be obsolete and erroneous.
2. Try to find the components which exist and which could help you. Add "ic" after the keyword. That's when you notice that the informations you got from others on the internet are obsolete. LOL.
3. Read datasheets carefully. Even when you think you know. Don't be lazy.
4. Draw a schematic, write a BOM file. Don't make mistake.
5. Make a prototype board and test it. Make a visual plan of the connections on you prototype board while you are soldering the parts and the wires. if you don;t do that, after, you forget.